# How to choose Build Configuration in Build Action in the Scheme dialog?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode4

In Xcode 4 preview 5 every time I hit 'build', Xcode now build my Project with the debug Configuration, how can I build, for example, with release configuration? My project is a dynamic library, so scheme actions like 'Run', 'Test', 'Profile' and 'Analyze' not really make sense to me.

As of Xcode 4 preview 5 the 'Build' scheme action has changed.

Setting up a scheme with scheme actions that use particular build configurations allows me to set up a scheme that runs the product with the Debug configuration but profiles it with the Release configuration.

Every scheme action has a drop-down menu to choose a build configuration, except the build action. Where did this option go?

Answer (score -1):

xCode 4 is under NDA until the final build is released. You should repost your question in https://devforums.apple.com/ for now